# Number of oblong rectangles up to similarity having integer side lengths in [1, r]

Tags: geometry, rectangles

> How many oblong rectangles are there up to similarity which have integer side lengths between (and including) $1$ and $r$ for $r\in\Bbb Z^+$?

This is a problem I set for myself for fun a few hours ago, but I still don't know where to begin. Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the dimensions of a rectangle are $a×b$; without loss of generality we can assume $a\ge b$ since swapping dimensions yields a similar rectangle.

Now fix $a$ and vary $b$; the rectangle is dissimilar from all smaller rectangles if and only if $\gcd(a,b)=1$. The number of values $b$ that cause this condition to be satisfied for some $a$ is the *definition* of the [Euler totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $\varphi(a)$; for example, $\varphi(6)=2$ since only the $6×1$ and $6×5$ rectangles are dissimilar from all smaller rectangles.

The number of rectangles up to similarity that have integer side lengths in $[1,r]$ is then the sum of totients:
$$S(r)=\sum_{k=1}^r\varphi(k)$$
and this function is [A002088](https://oeis.org/A002088) in the OEIS. The first few values of $S(r)$ starting from $r=1$ are below.
$$1, 2, 4, 6, 10, 12, 18, 22, 28, 32, 42, 46,\dots$$
Note that this also counts the $1×1$ *square* at the very beginning; if you want rectangles in the strict sense just subtract 1 from the values listed above.
$$0, 1, 3, 5, 9, 11, 17, 21, 27, 31, 41, 45,\dots$$
This is also in the OEIS, as [A015614](https://oeis.org/A015614).